# why animated gif link is broken on laravel project on xampp?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, animated-gif

I have embedded a gif image from imgur in a laravel project. While any external jpeg, png link perfectly displays on the blade, whenever I replace with gif it gets broken. I am using xampp local server.
**code snippet**

```
<div class="card mb-3">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/juuaqEg.gif" alt="Imgur" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;height: 30vw; object-fit:cover; " alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">List of Students</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a comprehensive panel for student management. Click buttons to make changes.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: broken gif on xampp]

I replaced the imgur link with a static jpeg/png image link and there is no problem to render. Don't laravel allow animated gif from external links?

Comment: Check if your browser block the request. You can check from "inspect elements" menu and then in network tab

Comment: Laravel is a backend framework. This means that it is impossible for Laravel to block a request

Comment: Please right click on the broken image  to see which error is displayed and/or riight click "open image in new tab"  Also please inspect the html code of that page.  I just opened the image on my computer and  so it should open on yours too ;-).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
  <img src="{{ URL::asset('https://i.imgur.com/juuaqEg.gif') }}" alt="Imgur" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;height: 30vw; object-fit:cover; " alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">List of Students</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a comprehensive panel for student management. Click buttons to make changes.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

else try downloading the gif in public folder (of your proyect) and calling

```
<img src="./nameOfTheFile.gif" alt="Imgur" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;height: 30vw; object-fit:cover; " alt="...">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it